# Change the content of a <td> using Prototype?

Tags: javascript, html-table, prototypejs

I have this table cell:

```
<td align="left">
    <img title="some title" src="image url">
</td>
```

I want to change the src (image url) but don't know how. Is that possible using Prototype or/and innerhtml or something? Do I need to give an id to the `<td>`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the element using Prototype’s `$` method and change its `src` property:

```
$('image').src = 'new-image.png';
```

If you have more than one image in the document, I’d suggest adding a class or ID to the image or the containing `<td>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know prototype, but there is a CSS selector for attributes that looks like

```
.img[title="some title"]
```

In jquery where you have sizzle, that can be used, not sure about prototype.

Comment: Figured it out myself, its not that hard:

`$('image').src = newimage;`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to obtain a reference to the specific node element in the DOM.

There are a number of ways to do this, you could reference the `img` by id.  You could loop over elements in the DOM (either rows/columns in your table, or across all `img` tags, etc.)

From there it's a simple reassignment of the `src` attribute.  Note: when you swap the `src` attribute of the `img` element it may not load immediately and may look unpleasant particularly for mouseover or button effects.  (After the initial load it may be cached by the browser and no longer be noticeable).

The suggested route is to pre-load such images for example:

```
var myImg = new Image();
myImg.src = "newimage.jpg";
```

Then you would set the node reference's `src` attribute to `myImg.src`.